# How many sequences of rational numbers converging to 1 are there?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, convergence-divergence, rational-numbers

I have a problem with this exercise:

> How many sequences of rational numbers converging to 1 are there?

I know that the number of all sequences of rational numbers is $\mathfrak{c}$. But here we count sequences converging to 1 only, so the total number is going to be less. But is it going to be $\mathfrak{c}$ still or maybe $\aleph _0$?

Comment: If $x_n\rightarrow0$, then $1\pm x_n\rightarrow 1$ for any choice of signs.

Comment: So the number of the sequences converging to 1 is equal to number of the sequences converging to 0.
But what now?

Comment: encode in $x_n$ a sequence of bits, so that the answer is $\ge$ than $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$. then considering a general sequence of rationnal numbers (not constrainted to converge to $1$) show that the answer is $\le$ than $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$

Comment: I don't trust my math skills enough to make this an answer without someone double checking me, but the function 1/(x-1) should map all rational numbers numbers not equal to 1 to a rational number.  Any sequence converging on 1 should then map to a sequence going out to infinity.  It should be easier to see why there are continuum sequences which go to infinity.

Comment: @user1952009 $2^{\aleph_0}$ isn't necessarily $\aleph_1$ - that equality is the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis), which is independent of ZFC. ($2^{\aleph_0}$ does however equal $|\mathbb R|$)

Comment: ok, maybe, what I meant with $2^{\aleph_0}$ was the "cardinal of the set of bits sequences", so that the proof I proposed should be ok (take a sequence $x_n$ converging to $1$, and hide in it a sequence of bits, for example at the $n$th bit of the decimal representation of $x_n$)

Comment: "But here we count sequences converging to 1 only, so the total number is going to be less."  Whoa!!  The absolute *first* intuition one should develop when dealing with infinity is that restrictions does *not* imply "less".  There are not fewer even numbers than integers.  You can add an infinite number of guests to Hilbert's hotel.  So intuitively your first impression should be there's the same number; not less.  Now, that's not enough to answer the question but it's a good intuitive starting point.

Comment: How many infinite subsets of $\{1+\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N_+\}$ are there?

Comment: can one describe/construct all such sequences from the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that non-repeating (injective) sequences of elements in $\{\,1+1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\,\}$ form a continuum, and all of them have limit $1$, so our set is at least a continuum. Since also all rational sequences form a continuum, our set is also at most a continuum.

Answer (score 27):

The number of sequence of rational numbers converging to $1$ is not countable. Suppose you get all squences by $(a_n^{(1)})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, (a_n^{(2)})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, (a_n^{(3)})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}, \dotsc$ Define a sequence $(b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by
$$b_{k}:=\begin{cases}1 & a_k^{(k)}\neq 1\\ 1+\frac{1}{n}& a_k^{(k)}= 1 \end{cases}$$
Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$ but $(b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\neq (a_n^{(i)})_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Is it possible to prove it's $2^{\aleph_0}$ without CH?

Comment: @Kevin:  Yes.  At position $n$ in the sequence, you can have $1+\frac 1n$ or $1$.  That is in bijection with the reals in $(0,1)$ expressed in binary.

Answer (score 12):

For each real number $x$ define
$$a_n(x):= 1+ \frac{ \lfloor xn \rfloor}{n^2}$$

Show that this is a one-to-one function from $\mathbb R$ to the set of sequences converging to $1$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That means that the function is not ONTO... I never said anything about that ;)

Comment: Oh. Duh. I hate the term "one-to-one" because, to me, it sounds much more like it means "bijective" than "injective" so I always make that mistake.

Answer (score 10):

I believe there is a continuum number of such sequences. For ease of writing, let's try to equivalently count the number of sequences converging to $0$. First note that there are countably many rational numbers in the interval $[-a,a]$. Now set for every sequence we will consider $x_i \in [\frac{-1}{i},\frac{1}{i}]$, so that each sequence of $x_i$'s will converge to $0$. The number of such sequences is equivalent to the number of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself, which is provably uncountable.

Comment: the question was indeed how to prove that the number of such sequences is the number of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself ?

Comment: You have demonstrated there is _at least_ a continuum of such sequences.  Can you provide an upper bound?

Comment: @JanDvorak:  OP correctly said the number of all sequences of rationals is $\mathfrak c$.  The ones converging to $0$ are a subset of these, so $\mathfrak c$ is an upper bound.

Answer (score 7):

$q \pm \frac{1}n$ is a sequence converging to $q$ for any sequence of $\pm$ signs.

That is a lower bound matching the stated upper bound.  This solves the problem in the sense that the Schroeder Bernstein principle applies. Finding a specific 1-1 correspondence between rational convergent sequences and 0-1 sequences is more complicated.

Comment: Isn't simply $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ a continuum, whence also $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ is?

Comment: The convergent sequences are a superset of a copy of 2^N from the +- signs, and a subset of a Q^N.  But this is a Schroeder-Bernstein argument, not a direct bijection to 2^N.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a sequence of rationals $(a_i)$ that converges
strictly monotonically to $1$ from above, that is, for all $i$,
$a_i > a_{i+1}$.
Consider an arbitrary sequence of non-negative integers $(c_k)$.
Construct a subsequence of $(a_i)$ by skipping the first $c_0$
elements of $(a_i)$ and set $b_0$ to the next element of $(a_i)$;
then skip another $c_1$ elements of $(a_i)$ and 
set $b_1$ to the next element of $(a_i)$;
then skip another $c_2$ elements of $(a_i)$, and so forth.
This produces a sequence $(b_k)$ which is a subsequence of $(a_i)$.

Any two distinct sequences of integers $(c_k)$, $(d_k)$ 
will produce two distinct subsequences of $(a_i)$ via this procedure.
For if $m$ is the least integer such that $c_m \neq d_m$, the
first $m$ elements of the subsequences produced for $(c_k)$ and $(d_k)$
will be equal, but the next elements will be different, since we skip
different numbers of elements to find the next element of each subsequence,
and no two elements of $(a_i)$ are equal.

That is, following this procedure, for every sequence of non-negative
integers there is a unique sequence of rationals that converges to $1$.
Let $A$ be the set of all sequences of non-negative integers
and $S$ be the set of all sequences of rationals converging to $1$;
we have shown that $\left\vert{A}\right\vert \leq \left\vert{S}\right\vert$.

But of course every sequence of rationals converging to $1$ is
a sequence of rationals, so if $B$ is the set of all sequences of rationals,
$\left\vert{S}\right\vert \leq \left\vert{B}\right\vert$.

But we also know that 
$\left\vert{A}\right\vert = \left\vert{B}\right\vert = \mathfrak{c}$.
That is, $\mathfrak{c} \leq \left\vert{S}\right\vert$
and $\left\vert{S}\right\vert \leq \mathfrak{c}$.
It follows that $\left\vert{S}\right\vert = \mathfrak{c}$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, by Cantor's diagonal it can't be $\aleph_0$.  (If it were, list all the sequences; change the i-th term of the i-th sequence; the resulting sequence converges to 1 but wasn't on the list.)

So the question is, is it going to be any cardinality between $\aleph_0$ and $\mathfrak{c}$.

hmm, don't think that's possible.  But I'm weak on my theory.  I'd think if $\{a_n\} \rightarrow r \in \mathbb R$ then $a_n/r \le b_n \le a_n/r + 1/n; b_n \in \mathbb Q$, then $\{b_n\} \rightarrow 1$.  So I think it must be $\mathfrak{c}$.